# Soundcloud API sc.stream (track not loading on mobile sometime) - working on desktop

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

We are currently using the soundcloud API SDK for streaming and it does work on desktop but not 100% on mobile. (using responsive html. same api of course)

- Sometime track is not lauch ? sometime it is.

I do not have specific error but on chrome network this line is show in red ??

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/146926142/stream?client_id=XXXXX
Redirect

We use a function to stream the track.

```
function streamTrack(id) {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            // Stream the track
            SC.stream('/tracks/' + id, {
                useHTML5Audio: false,
                waitForWindowLoad: true,
                onfinish: _scope.next,
                whileplaying: function () {
                    var _this = this;

                    // Since we are in a callback, we need to tell angularJS to apply the change
                    if (timeout1) $timeout.cancel(timeout1);
                    timeout1 = $timeout(function () {
                        // Update the progress bar
                        _scope.progress = (_this.position / currentTrackDuration * 100) + '%';
                        _scope.timer = moment(_this.position).format('mm:ss');

                        $rootScope.$broadcast('trackRunning', { timerunning: _scope.timer });
                    });
                }
            }, function (sound) {
                if (sound) {
                    defer.resolve(sound);
                } else {
                    defer.reject();
                }
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
```

If somebody has an idea pls.

Best Regards
Xavier

Comment: dont know really - but if you disable html5, it will use flash - which is may be not supported on some mobile browser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-), nevertheless that has no effect :-/. It seems that google chrome android is blocking something as we do not have this behaviour on IOS